# How to pass query string parameters in ckeditor for the picture (ckfinder) button?

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using ckeditor 3 and ckfinder. When I press on the picture button in ckeditor I see the popup of ckfinder. I can select a picture and it will be inserted in the content of ckeditor. Now I would like to pass some query string parameters in the ckfinder popup. In the connector I would like to read this query string parameter.

For example:

```
connectorBuilder.SetAuthenticator(customAuthenticator)
                .LoadConfig()
                .SetRequestConfiguration(
                    (request, config) =>
                    {
                       var someQueryStringParameter = request.QueryParameters.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Key == "someQueryStringParameter").Value;
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't know which CKFinder you're using but for CKFinder 3 (with CKEditor 4) you can use [connectrInfo](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Config-cfg-connectorInfo) when using [CKFinder.setupCKEditor()](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder-method-setupCKEditor) integration method (pass it in `config` object). Also check [CKEditor integration docs](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckfinder/ckfinder3/#!/guide/dev_ckeditor).

> In the connector I would like to read this query string parameter.

It is important to note that these parameters from `connctorInfo` will not be added to URL in popup but to requests directed to CKFinder. For configuration like:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {     
    height:350
} );
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, {
    connectorInfo : 'mytoken=7a9s0s1',
    pass : 'test,another',
    test : 'mytest',
    another : 'myanother'           
} );
```

the result will be as follows: [image]